# Python JSON TypeError list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json

I am currently trying to parse some data from a post request response and I keep getting this error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Python Code

```
import requests
import json

count = 0
params = {'var1':'40', 'value':'143', 'itm':'1', 'param':'1'}


req = 'https://www.api.com/api/search'
data = requests.post(req, data = params).json()

print (data['result']['results']['name'])
```

JSON Response

```
{  
   "result":{  
      "count":1,
      "totalCount":1,
      "offset":0,
      "queryTime":232,
      "results":[  
         {  
            "rating":"4.0",
            "productId":{  
               "upc":"143",
               "ItemId":"143",
               "productId":"143-prd"
            },
            "name":"Product",
            "catagory":{  
               "name":"",
               "CataId":1
            },
            "images":{  
               "thumbnailUrl":"http://api.com/img/static/product-image-50-50.png",
               "largeUrl":"http://api.com/img/static/product-image-500-500.png"
            },
            "price":{  
               "price":13,
               "isRealTime":true,
               "currencyUnit":"USD"
            },
            "location":{  
               "unit":[],
               "detailed":[]
            },
            "inventory":{  
               "quantity":1,
               "status":"In Stock",
               "isRealTime":true
            },
            "ratings":{  
               "rating":"3.1875",
               "ratingUrl":"http://api.com/3_1875.gif"
            },
            "reviews":{  
               "reviewCount":"2"
            },
            "isItem":true,
            "lUrl":"/l/Product-Name"
         }
      ],
      "performance":{  
         "enrichment":{  

         }
      },
      "query":{  
         "originalQuery":"143",
         "actualQuery":"143",
         "suggestedQueries":[  

         ]
      },
      "algo":"jarvis",
      "blacklist":false,
      "cluster":{  
         "apiserver":{  
            "hostname":"site.api.com",
            "pluginVersion":"1.0"
         },
         "searchengine":{  
            "hostname":"srch.site.api.com"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I did a similar piece of code but it was a get request and everything turned out fine.

Comment: `data['result']['results']` is an array so you can't do `['name']` you need an int, you could add `[0]` before `['name']` and it should work

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks!

Comment: Instead of adding `[0]` you could also iterate through results in case there is more than one result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`data['result']['results']` is an array so you can't do `['name']` you need an int, you could add `[0]` after`['results']` and it should work. Then you can reference keys within the object in `results`.

Comment: the `[0]` should remain after `['results']` since that is a list

Comment: Brackets (`[`and `]`) delineate the start and stop of a JSON list.   Lists require numeric indexes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

```
    [
        {
            "_index": "abc",
            "_type": "abc",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              "layers": {
                "frame_raw": [
                "frame": {
                ......
                "raw": [
```

Correct way to access "raw" values is

```
    data = json.load(json_file)
    data[0]['_source']['layers']['raw'][0]
    data[0]['_source']['layers']['raw'][1]

...
```

In case of multiple data:

```
    [
        {
            "_index": "abc",
            "_type": "abc",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              "layers": {
                "frame_raw": [
                "frame": {
                ......
                "raw": [

        {
            "_index": "abc",
            "_type": "abc",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              "layers": {
                "frame_raw": [
                "frame": {
                ......
                "raw": [
```

Get it by:

```
    data = json.load(json_file)
            for d in data:
                print(d['_source']['layers']['raw'][0])
```