# How do I find the element in this XML document?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I am trying to find the text in a few elements in an XML document in python. Here is a snippet of the XML Document followed by my code:

```
<root>
   <doc>
      <field name="id">metadata_9606_SAMN03465421</field>
      <field name="is_metadata">true</field>
      <field name="is_sample">true</field>
      <field name="project_desc">PRJNA280600</field>
      <field name="taxid">9606</field>
      <field name="source_name">uterus</field>
      <field name="sample_id">SAMN03465421</field>
      <field name="exp_Mcount">13341.1</field>
   </doc>
   <doc>
      <field name="id">1_SAMN03465421</field>
      <field name="gene">1</field>
      <field name="sample_id">SAMN03465421</field>
<field name="source_name">uterus</field><field name="var">0</field>
      <field name="full_rpkm">0.133911</field>
      <field name="exp_rpkm">0.134</field>
      <field name="exp_total">3155</field>
      <field name="project_desc">PRJNA280600</field>
   </doc>
   <doc>
      <field name="id">1_SAMN03465420</field>
      <field name="gene">1</field>
      <field name="sample_id">SAMN03465420</field>
<field name="source_name">trachea</field><field name="var">0</field>
      <field name="full_rpkm">0.0232912</field>
      <field name="exp_rpkm">0.0233</field>
      <field name="exp_total">604</field>
      <field name="project_desc">PRJNA280600</field>
   </doc>
</root>
```

Here is my code:

```
import lxml.etree
tree = lxml.etree.parse(<PATH TO DOCUMENT>)
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.findall('/doc/field name[4]'))
```

I would like to print the <s>fourth "field name" in each "doc" element that contains the XPATH I am looking for</s>  fourth field text of each element with the name "source_name". I am getting this error when I run this code though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/gene_expression_ftp/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(root.findall('/doc/field name[4]'))
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1575, in lxml.etree._Element.findall
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 334, in lxml._elementpath.findall
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 312, in lxml._elementpath.iterfind
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 281, in lxml._elementpath._build_path_iterator
SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element
```

Comment: What does the fourth "field name" in each "doc" element mean? Please show us the exact output that you want. For example, the fourth "field" element in the first "doc" has the text content `PRJNA280600`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I've edited the post to better reflect what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def search():
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    tree = ET.parse('file.xml')

    root = tree.getroot()
   
    for doc in root.findall("doc"):
       for item in doc:
           print(item.attrib['name'])
```

Comment: sorry there was an error try it now  it returns all name

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using an interesting library called xmltodict: [Finding element in xml with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54651689/finding-element-in-xml-with-python) . These are the Docs: https://xmltodict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/README/ .

Here is my code:

```
with open(<PATH TO FILE>, 'r') as gene_exps:
    data = xmltodict.parse(gene_exps.read())

for i in data['root']['doc']:
    for item in i.get('field'):
        if item.get('@name') == 'source_name':
            print(item.get('#text'))
```

Comment: This code prints the text value of each `field` element that has a `name="source_name"` attribute. That does not seem to be what you are asking for in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to reflect better what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fourth field of each doc, that's `/root/doc/field[4]`.

If you want the field named "source_name", that's `/root/doc/field[@name='source_name"]`.

If you want a field provided it is both the fourth field and has the name "source name", that's `/root/doc/field[4][@name='source_name"]`

But you haven't made it clear which of these you are looking for.