# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in python loop

Tags: python, loops

I've looked for other answers, ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591062/python-json-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)) for example and haven't had any luck.  I am writing a script to pull data from an API.

I want to loop through the resulting dictionary and pull out specifics for each result, such as name, population, etc. A sample of the resulting response using json.dumps is this:

```
{
    "count": 61,
    "next": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "climate": "temperate",
            "created": "2014-12-10T11:35:48.479000Z",
            "diameter": "12500",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T20:58:18.420000Z",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/",
                "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/"
            ],
            "gravity": "1 standard",
            "name": "Alderaan",
            "orbital_period": "364",
            "population": "2000000000",
            "residents": [
                "https://swapi.co/api/people/5/",
                "https://swapi.co/api/people/68/",
                "https://swapi.co/api/people/81/"
            ],
            "rotation_period": "24",
            "surface_water": "40",
            "terrain": "grasslands, mountains",
            "url": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/"
        },
        {
            "climate": "temperate, tropical",
            "created": "2014-12-10T11:37:19.144000Z",
            "diameter": "10200",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T20:58:18.421000Z",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/"
            ],
            "gravity": "1 standard",
            "name": "Yavin IV",
            "orbital_period": "4818",
            "population": "1000",
            "residents": [],
            "rotation_period": "24",
            "surface_water": "8",
            "terrain": "jungle, rainforests",
            "url": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/3/"
        },
        {
            "climate": "frozen",
            "created": "2014-12-10T11:39:13.934000Z",
            "diameter": "7200",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T20:58:18.423000Z",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.co/api/films/2/"
            ],
            "gravity": "1.1 standard",
            "name": "Hoth",
            "orbital_period": "549",
            "population": "unknown",
            "residents": [],
            "rotation_period": "23",
            "surface_water": "100",
            "terrain": "tundra, ice caves, mountain ranges",
            "url": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/4/"
        },
```

New to Python, so if there is a better way to do this, I'm open for suggestions!

In my code for testing I have this:

```
print(jsonResponse["results"][1]["name"])
```

I can manually change the 1 to other numbers and get the correct name to print out.

If I use this I get the "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" message

```
for i in jsonResponse:
            print(jsonResponse["results"][i]["name"])
```

Comment: `for i in jsonResponse:` does not give numerical indices. You want: `for item in jsonResponse['results']: print(item['name'])`

Comment: Why not `for elem in jsonResponse["results"]: print(elem["name"])`?

Comment: The meaning of the error is that `i` certainly is not an integer, have you tried printing it maybe you meant `for i, response in enumerate(jsonResponse)`

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to loop over the elements in `jsonResponse["results"]`, not `jsonResponse`.
2. Your loop will provide the actual elements, not their indices.

Which gets you to:

```
for item in jsonResponse["results"]:
    print(item["name"])
```

Comment: Perfect, that seems to be working great for me.  Thank you!