# Python List indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json

Assuming my json response looks like this:

```
{
  "classifier_id" : "12345",
  "url" : "https://something.com",
  "text" : "text",
  "top_class" : "class1",
  "classes" : [ {
    "class_name" : "car",
    "confidence" : 0.9862312904583641
  }, {
    "class_name" : "bus",
    "confidence" : 0.013768709541636032
  } ]
}
```

with the underlying GET request being

```
callIBM = requests.get(
    url="https://something.com",
    params={
        "text": update.message.text,
    },
    headers={
        "Authorization": "XXX",
    },
)
```

and I want to parse the result in python.

I tried:

```
ibmscore1 = '{}'.format(callIBM.json()["classes"][0]["class_name"]["confidence"])
ibmscore2 = '{}'.format(callIBM.json()["classes"][1]["class_name"]["confidence"])
```

but it's not working. Could one kindly assist a python newby?

Comment: This `callIBM.json()["classes"][0]["class_name"]` is a `string`, not a `dict`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python JSON TypeError list indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591062/python-json-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `confidence` inside `class_name` but `class_name` is not a dictionary.

Try:

```
resp = callIBM.json()
class1, conf1 = resp["classes"][0]["class_name"], resp["classes"][0]["confidence"]
class2, conf2 = resp["classes"][1]["class_name"], resp["classes"][0]["confidence"]
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not working, however, TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation.

Comment: @j___.___j I don't think this error is related to my snippet as I have no indentation in my code

Comment: If I just paste/replace my code with yours, the error occurs :(

Comment: The question is where did you paste it :) Could you edit your question and share your code with the error/traceback?